# My app got rejected from google play due to some issue with network policy?

Tags: android, google-play, licensing, publish

Following is the message--
and had to reject it because it violates our device and network abuse policy and section 4.4 of the **Developer Distribution Agreement**. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still live on Google Play.

Here’s how you can submit your app for another review:

Modify your app to make sure it doesn’t access or use a service or API in a manner that violates its terms of service; for example, by enabling background play of YouTube videos. Read through the Device and Network Abuse policy for more details and examples. Make sure your app is compliant with all other policies listed in the Developer Program Policies. Remember that additional enforcement could occur if there are further policy issues with your apps.Sign in to your Developer Console and submit your app.

My app has a button which opens **WhatsApp** directly from it and also I have included youtube website.

Please tell me whats the problem

Comment: I have the same issue. How did y solve in this case ? please share me what  y find

Comment: I don't use Youtube API but I don't understand why my app has been rejected :(

Comment: Have you solved the issue? I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44532286/6398434) and it worked.

Answer (score 64):

Several times now I've had apps uploaded on the playstore, a few days later, they'll reject it saying, for example, it violates the metadata rules, please read our Metadata rules.

They sent me a link, I clicked on the link and did a search for 'metadata'
Nowhere on the page is metadata mentioned.

They must have a very specific reason for rejection, which I'd be happy to correct, if only they'd tell me specifically why it was rejected.
Instead, they give some broad, general term, and just tell you you've violated
their terms, please all of our terms, and re submit.
But they don't tell you specifically what they've rejected the app for.

They must know why they have rejected the app, specifically.
But it's like, we've rejected you app, but we're not going to tell you why, 
you'll have to work it out for yourself.
It's like they enjoy having developers wading through pages and pages of
requirements to try to work out why they now violate terms and conditions, when
yesterday, you were compliant.

Comment: If they tell you specific reason, there will be much less policy violation submissions, which means google doesn't need to hire too many people doing manual review, and those rejecting your submission will lose their jobs.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue for my app. I was displaying Banner Ads in the webview screen where user watch Youtube video. According to Google Play program policy, we are not allow to show BANNER ADS in those screen where we are accessing Youtube video.

Look at my picture which i got my from Google Play Support team.

[image]

Comment: Did they send you that the first time they rejected your app or you had to ask for more specific information about the rejection? Because they're not that straightforward

Answer (score 3):

For the additional info, The 4.4 of [developer-distribution-agreement](https://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html) is

> **Prohibited Actions :** You agree that you will not engage in any activity with the Store, including the development or distribution of Products, that interferes with, disrupts, damages, or accesses in an unauthorized manner the devices, servers, networks, or other properties or services of any third party including, but not limited to, Android users, Google or any mobile network operator. You may not use customer information obtained from the Store to sell or distribute Products outside of the Store.

The another review suggestion you're getting is simply explaining the cause of violation,

> It doesn’t access or use a service or API in a manner that violates its terms of service; for example, by enabling background play of YouTube videos.

That means you probably forgot to pause the video when your app is in background,

Better referring [How to stop youtube video playing in Android webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946698/how-to-stop-youtube-video-playing-in-android-webview) instead, and try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25380464/5067493) answer as well where the webview's onPause method is called in `onPause()` like.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mWebView.onPause();
}
```

Comment: I think i must remove that youtube section

Comment: I have also included a button which opens whatsapp on clicking ,  so will that harm ??

Comment: It's not complaining about whatsapp, And it's your choice to remove or keep the youtube section without violating the terms.

Answer (score 2):

After many attempts and sleepless nights, I finally got to publish my app.

First I put the following code on my webview activity:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView webview, String url) {
            super.onLoadResource(webview, url);
            if (url.contains("youtube.com")) mShouldPause = true;
        }

    });


@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(mShouldPause){
        myWebView.onPause();
    }
    mShouldPause = false;
}
```

And the most important thing is that on manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

I have made so many tests, and I don't think the problem is really youtube videos on background, because I've try without any link from youtube and the app don't submmit on Google Play, it just work after put a permission on manifest file.

I hope that help someone

Comment: Are you using Ionic 2? Really struggling with this. Which file is the webview activity please?

Comment: @me9867 me too, did you know how to fix this problem? Please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe it is the video playing issue at all that keeps Android apps not being approved.

Just add this line to your app manifest and presto app auto approved.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Also for those using Cordova (PhoneGap) add the plugin called cordova-custom-config in order to add to the manifest:

```
Name ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

Value: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: I suspect you're right. I had unistalled and dettached Firebase, Crashlytics, Google Services, AdSense/AdMob, Google Analytics and Remarketing and ID and my app was reject when I tried to update. I received the e-mail about Network policy and then I did what you suggested. Everything is running fine now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a insult on my app's description. I just had to put a * on the word, and that solved it. Incredible...