# Policy issue in using Youtube API

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube, google-play, google-play-services

Our app uses the Video ID to show the videos in Youtube players. We just locally store the video ID.

We have published the app, but it got rejected with below reason stating.

> It violates our device and network abuse policy. If you submitted an
>   update, the previous version of your app is still live on Google Play.
>
> Here’s how you can submit your app for another review:
>
> Your app shouldn’t access or use a service or API in a manner that
>   violates its terms of service. For example, make sure your app doesn’t
>   download, monetize, or access YouTube videos in a way that violates
>   the YouTube Terms of Service.

We dont no how to ask support to team of Google play services to know what is the mistake exactly happened here.

Please help us

Comment: Try checking the [Youtube TOS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms), to see if your app is conforming to given TOS as sa)id in the related [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38045817/5995040). This will you pin point what terms you are violating like enabling background play of YouTube videos. Hope this helps.

Comment: today i faced same problem. my app rejected. did you find any solution?

Comment: You need to write email to support team, also if you are really using the copyrighted contents or modifying the contents then you have to get approval from original author. Also avoid using the copyright logos and etc in your application... this will help