# Enabling background play of YouTube videos

Tags: codenameone

My app had to reject it because it violates our device and network abuse policy .
They told "Modify your app to make sure it doesn’t access or use a service or API in a manner that violates its terms of service; for example, by enabling background play of YouTube videos."
How I enabling background play of YouTube videos?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds similar to this issue:

[Android App rejection from Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730711/android-app-rejection-from-google-play)

So it looks like you must have a web view that allows playing youtube videos, and they will continue to play when the app is put into the background.  That, apparently is against youtube's policy.

So, looks like you'll need to deal with this case inside your lifecycle's "stop" method, to pause or stop the youtube video when your app goes into the background.